# How to create modal type in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create model type for the below value (interface) in angular 4,

```
          [{ "id": "CC", "value": "Connect Orlando" },
           {"id": "CB", "value": "Connect Bengaluru"},
           {"id": "CS", "value": "Connect Mumbai" }]
```

i tried something like below

```
export class DropdownModel {
    public options: DropdownOptionsModel[];
}

export class DropdownOptionsModel {
    public id: any;
    public value: any;
}
```

but getting error **"property option is missing"** in the below line

```
this.mergedList= <DropdownModel> this.mergeValue(this.serviceCall.list1 ,this.serviceCall.list2 );

 private mergeValue(list1, list2) {
        let merged = [];
        for (let list of list1) {
            merged.push(list);
        }
        for (let list of list2) {
            merged.push(list);
        }
        return merged;
    }
```

i was trying to merge two arrays and storing it inside mergedList variable.

Comment: which line throws this error

Comment: @Sajeetharan updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should simply be this

```
export class DropdownOptionsModel {
    public id: any;
    public value: any;
}
```

Your result is an array of `DropdownOptionsModel` => `DropdownOptionsModel[]`

---

What you're saying here is:

```
export class DropdownModel {
    public options: DropdownOptionsModel[];
}
```

I have an object that has an options property that stores an array of `{ id, value }`

Comment: i am using array of list but using export class DropdownOptionsModel {
    public id: any;
    public value: any;
} is fine ? we no need to mention [ ] in the model ???

Comment: now getting this error -- >  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'DropdownModel'.
  Property 'id' is missing in type 'any[]'.

Comment: @Munna No, the definition of a model is always singular. When you're retrieving the data from `http`, you can retrieve a `DropdownOptionsModel[]` if you need to.

Comment: @Munna Make sure you annotate the types of what you're working with when writing TypeScript. Otherwise you'll end up with a `any` object that will have to force casted to the type you want. Either way, something like this will work: `const a: DropdownOptionsModel[] = [{ id: 1, value: "123" }]`